SPARQL request on qualifiers?
I saw the following SPARQL query successfully requesting Publication date (P577) qualifiers (link) :
SELECT ?title ?item ?date ?place ?placeLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  ?item wdt:P161 wd:Q38111.
  ?item wdt:P1476 ?title.
  # Get qualifiers
  ?item p:P577 ?statement. 
  ?statement ps:P577 ?date. 
  ?statement pq:P291 ?place.
}

I replicated this grammar to request Pronunciation (P443) qualifiers, but the following fails (link) :
SELECT ?id ?idLabel ?audio ?audioLabel ?audioFile ?audioLangLabel ?speakerLabel
WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  ?id wdt:P443 ?audio.
  FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?audio), "LL-Q117707514")) # occitan whistled -Q117707514
  # ?id wdt:P625 ?coord . # geocoordinates
  OPTIONAL {  
    ?id p:443 ?audioStatement .
    ?audioStatement ps:P443 ?audioFile.
    ?audioStatement pq:P407 ?audioLang.
    ?audioStatement pq:P10894 ?speaker.
    }
}

Any clue ?

The property is p:P443 (http://www.wikidata.org/prop/P443), not p:443.

Me right now :
A) Horror and screams
B) Relief and happyness
Answer : A & B.
``` THANK YOU !
